Stripe subscription with a trial period goes to status trial even if the payment fails
I've recently migrated from the stripe card element to the new PaymentElements just so I can support apple pay and google pay aswell as cards for my subscriptions. I've been going round in circles through stripes docs on how to properly setup a subscription.
Right now, I'm setting up a customer right at the very beginning of my user journey, I then get them to fill out there information and there payment information, then in my form submit, I submit the user, the backend creates the user, then creates the subscription, the webhooks do the rest. What I' having an issue with, is when a card payment fails, the payment status goes straight to trailing in my webhook. Even though the setup intent technically fails I guess. How can I leave it as incomplete, just like if there wasn't a free trial period.
I've had to change my whole flow too, I'd much prefer it if a user just wasn't created in my database (like before) when the payment fails, as I could confirm the payment on my backend which was much nicer, now I have to create a user regardless, and retreive the subscription if its incomplete. Really feel like I've messed my stuff up now, if there was a way to create a user after I confirm it works that would be even better. Without doing a whole redirect_url stuffed with user params.
Backend code.
  createSubscriptionAndUser: protectedProcedure
.input(inputSchemaCreateSubscription)
.mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
  const planPriceIds = {
    Silver: env.STRIPE_PRICE_ID_SILVER,
    Gold: env.STRIPE_PRICE_ID_GOLD,
    Platinum: env.STRIPE_PRICE_ID_PLATINUM,
  };

  const clerkUser = ctx.auth.userId
    ? await clerkClient.users.getUser(ctx.auth.userId)
    : null;

  const gymsToConnect = input.gyms.map((gym) => ({ id: gym.value }));
  const trainingToConnect = input.training.map((training) => ({
    id: training.value,
  }));

  const selectedPlanFromUser: keyof typeof planPriceIds = input.plan;

  let customer;
  const email = clerkUser?.emailAddresses[0]?.emailAddress ?? "";

  const customers = await ctx.stripe.customers.list({ email });

  let customerId;
  if (customers?.data?.[0]?.id) {
    customerId = customers.data[0].id;
  }

  if (customerId) {
    customer = await ctx.stripe.customers.update(customerId, {
      name: `${clerkUser?.firstName ?? input.firstName} ${
        clerkUser?.lastName ?? input.lastName
      }`,
      metadata: {
        userId: ctx.auth.userId,
      },
    });
  } else {
    console.error("something bad happened");
    throw new TRPCError({ code: "BAD_REQUEST" });
  }

  const priceId = planPriceIds[selectedPlanFromUser];

  if (!clerkUser?.firstName || !clerkUser?.lastName) {
    await clerkClient.users.updateUser(ctx.auth.userId, {
      firstName: input.firstName,
      lastName: input.lastName,
    });
  }

  const doesUserAlreadyExist =
    await ctx.prisma.personalTrainerUser.findFirst({
      where: {
        id: ctx.auth.userId,
      },
    });

  if (
    doesUserAlreadyExist?.stripeSubscriptionId &&
    doesUserAlreadyExist?.subscriptionStatus === "incomplete"
  ) {
    const subscription = await ctx.stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
      doesUserAlreadyExist.stripeSubscriptionId,
      {
        expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent", "pending_setup_intent"],
      }
    );
    const subscriptionPayload = getSubscriptionPayload(subscription);

    return { user: doesUserAlreadyExist, subscriptionPayload };
  }

  const user = await ctx.prisma.personalTrainerUser.create({
    data: {
      id: ctx.auth.userId,
      stripeCustomerId: customer.id,
      avatar: clerkUser?.imageUrl,
      email,
      firstName: clerkUser?.firstName ?? input.firstName,
      lastName: clerkUser?.lastName ?? input.lastName,
      gender: input.gender,
      gyms: {
        connect: gymsToConnect,
      },
      expertise: {
        connect: trainingToConnect,
      },
      longitude: input.longitude,
      latitude: input.latitude,
      locationName: input.locationName,
      membershipLevel: input.plan,
      holiday: false,
    },
  });

  const subscription = await ctx.stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [
      {
        price: priceId,
      },
    ],
    expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent", "pending_setup_intent"],
    payment_behavior: "default_incomplete",
    payment_settings: { save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription" },
    trial_period_days: 30,
    metadata: {
      userId: ctx.auth.userId,
    },
  });
  const subscriptionPayload = getSubscriptionPayload(subscription);

  return { user, subscriptionPayload };
}),

Front end submission
const onSubmit = async (data: FormInputs) => {
if (currentStep === 1) {
  setCurrentStep(2);
} else {
  if (!stripe || !elements) {
    return;
  }
  setPaymentError(null); // Reset payment error state before processing

  const { error: submitError } = await elements.submit();
  if (submitError?.message) {
    setPaymentError(submitError.message);

    return;
  }

  const redirectUrl = window.location.origin + `/payment`;

  try {
    const { subscriptionPayload } = await createUserAndSubscriptionMutation(
      {
        plan: data.plan,
        gender: data.gender.value,
        longitude: data.location.longitude,
        latitude: data.location.latitude,
        locationName: data.location.locationName,
        gyms: data.gyms,
        training: data.training,
        firstName: user?.firstName ?? data.firstName,
        lastName: user?.lastName ?? data.lastName,
      }
    );
    setPaymentLoading(true);

    const confirmIntent =
      subscriptionPayload.type === "setup"
        ? stripe.confirmSetup.bind(stripe)
        : stripe.confirmPayment.bind(stripe);

    const { error } = await confirmIntent({
      elements,
      clientSecret: subscriptionPayload.clientSecret as string,
      confirmParams: {
        return_url: redirectUrl,
      },
    });
    if (error) {
      setPaymentLoading(false);
      console.error("Stripe error:", error.message);
      setPaymentError(
        error.message || "An error occurred while confirming payment."
      );
      setPaymentLoading(false);
    }
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    if (error instanceof TRPCClientError) {
      setPaymentError(error.message);
      console.error("tRPC error:", error.message);
      console.error("Error shape:", error.shape);
    } else if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.error("Some other error:", error.message);
    } else {
      console.error("Unknown error:", error);
    }
  }
}

};

With the custom elements flow (where you create the Subscription first then collect the payment method along with the first intent), this is a known limitation.
To my knowledge, the only feature that exists to control this is trial_settings.missing_payment_method=cancel, however this is still not quite what you want:

You want the Subscription to cancel or be inactive (i.e. not trialing) if the customer doesn't succeed the first setup intent.
trial_settings.missing_payment_method=cancel won't do that, but it will automatically cancel the Subscription if no method has been collected by the first payment invoice.

What's even more frustrating for you is that Stripe allows this, but with Checkout - with payment_method_collection=always, no Subscription will be created unless the customer completes the session - which entails collecting a valid payment method.
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?platform=web&ui=stripe-hosted
The way I would propose to solve it would be to move away from the new flow (where you create the Subscription first then collect the payment method along with the first intent), and instead use a more old-fashioned flow where you collect the payment method first, then create your Subscription. This would be a good "way to create a user after I confirm it works" as you put it.

Collect payment method with your own setup intent
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-and-reuse


If that succeeds:


Create Subscription with trial and those arguments:
default_payment_method=setup_intent.payment_method
off_session=true
The off_session argument is not really relevant for trials - it's useful to avoid the first payment of the Susbcription to require authentication, but that's naturally not a problem if you don't have a first payment.


thanks so much mate. I’ll give this ago, I’m so tired trying everything with this rubbish that I’m gonna go sit in the sun for abit, the payment part is now the most complex part of my app. Imagine xD

The good news is that you shouldn't have to change much > you should already have a setup intent confirmation form on the frontend - that can remain intact, the only difference is it will be used to confirm YOUR setup_intent, rather than the one generated by the Subscription (which happens later with this flow)

https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?platform=web&ui=elements
This is what I followed first, I create the customer at the beginning of the flow, I don't believe thats part of the intent right? Thats a separate thing.

ahh, it seems like there's not really a way I can avoid creating a user. Because even this flow has a redirect. I guess I create the subscription on the redirected url

Regarding customer creation, the documentation suggests creating it first, but you don't technically have to. What you could do is 1. create + confirm setup_intent (without customer) 2. on setup_intent.succeeded, create customer and attach setup_intent.payment_method to them 3. create subscription. My idea was that you could create the user on 3 as well, though that ultimately depends on your implementation
